# Can type families evaluate to qualified types such as `C a => T`?

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-level-computation

Is there any way to write a type family that sometimes evaluates to a constrained type such as `C a => T`?

This question arose when I was writing the following type family:

```
type family Function (cs :: [Constraint]) (as :: [Type]) (r :: Type) :: Type where
  Function (c ': cs) as        r = c => Function cs  as r
  Function '[]       (a ': as) r = a -> Function '[] as r
  Function '[]       '[]       r = r
```

The goal was that `Function '[Integral a, Show b] '[String, b, a] (IO ())` would evaluate to `Integral a => Show b => String -> b -> a -> IO ()`.  However, instead, I get the error

```
    • Illegal qualified type: c => Function cs as r
    • In the equations for closed type family ‘Function’
      In the type family declaration for ‘Function’
```

I tried using `Show c => Function cs as r` to see if the issue was with the bare `c`, but that didn't seem to make a difference.  I've tried this with `GHC2021` plus the extensions `ConstraintKinds`, `DataKinds`, `RankNTypes`, `TypeFamilies`, and `UndecidableInstances`, but I'm happy to add any other language extensions as well if they'll make a difference.

Is there any way to do this?  If not, why isn't it possible?

Comment: One possible operational consideration: I guess it's probably pretty hard to generate code for a value that must accept a statically-unknown number of typeclass dictionaries as arguments. That's my reading of what something with a type like `Function cs '[] ()` would need to do.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Oh, that makes sense.  It also explains why constraint tuples don’t reduce – similar attempts would generate `(C1 a, (C2 b, C3 c)) => …` and that’s distinct from `(C1 a, C2 b, C3 c)`, to what was my surprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This compiles. The trick is splitting the constraint part and the type part.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds #-}

import Data.Kind

-- Handle the list of constraints.
type family Context (cs :: [Constraint]) :: Constraint where
  Context (c ': cs) = (c, Context cs)
  Context '[]       = ()    

-- Handle the list of argument types.
type family Fun (as :: [Type]) (r :: Type) :: Type where
  Fun (a ': as) r = a -> Fun as r
  Fun '[]       r = r

-- Combine both.
type Function (cs :: [Constraint]) (as :: [Type]) (r :: Type)
  = (Context cs) => Fun as r
```

Comment: Oh nice!  This definitely works for that specific case, but I'm also wondering about the more general one – is there any way to generate constrained functions at all?

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky I'm not sure about why your code fails, to be honest. I don't fully understand how general constrained types like `T -> (c => U) -> V` exactly work. A long time ago, I thought that constraints could be used only after quantifiers e.g. `forall a . C a => ....` but nowadays more forms seem to be accepted.

Comment: I think they go where quantifiers go, so you need `RankNTypes`, but there don't need to be any quantified variables.  Anyway, thanks for the answer!  Some mysteries of GHC must remain mysterious :-)